# Map an element of an array as a column value in handsontable

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I am using the "[nested objects with column mappings](http://past.handsontable.com/demo/datasources.html#nested)" data source option for handsontable.

This works fantastic for the most part and I am loving this table.

I define my column mappings like this:

```
columnMappings = [
    { data: 'customer.lastName' },
    { data: 'customer.firstName' }
]
```

Those work great and show up in my grid.

But one of my nested objects is itself an array, and I want to show a value from the first element in that array:

```
{ data: 'orders[0].OrderedWhen' },
```

Unfortunately, this one column is not showing up in my grid.  I am guessing that handsontable does not understand the array reference.

I could make a copy of the data that is flattened, but there are quite a few rows, and I would rather access the data directly.

**Is there a way to access an array item in a row dataset in handsontable?**

Comment: did you try using dataSchema option?

Comment: @charlietfl All I could see about the dataScheme was an example using backbone.  I admit that I did not understand it.

Comment: seems like just a function to map data with. Using `get()` as in your answer seems simpler

Answer (score 0):

I added this to my row object:

```
// For Display Only
get order() {
    return this.orders[0];
}
```

Then changed my mapping to use my new property:

```
{ data: 'order.OrderedWhen' }
```

Not a handsontable solution, but it works.